# Как зарегистрировать два logging.Logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование

Есть вот такая функция регистрации `logger`

```py
import logging

def register_logger(
    base_path: PathLike[str],
    file_name: str,
    register_name: str | None,
    log_level: Any,
) -> logging.Logger:
    path = Path(base_path, f"{file_name}.log")
    logger = logging.getLogger(register_name)
    logger.setLevel(level=log_level)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(path, encoding="utf8")
    formatter = logging.Formatter("\n%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s\n%(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

Нужно зарегистрировать два обработчика: один безымянный, второй с именем. Условно это выглядит так:

```py
logger = register_logger(path, "server", None, 1)
logger_web = register_logger(path, "web", "web", 1)

# И допустим в другом файле
logger_web = logging.getLogger("web")
```

Но, при попытке использования `logger_web.error(...)`, последний дублирует записи в оба файла. При этом безымянный `logger` пишет только в свой файл `.../path/server.log`.

Что здесь может быть не так, и как избежать дублирования записей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что когда создается логгер без имени, то он называется `root` логгер:

```
logger = register_logger(path, "server", None, 1)
```

Он есть по умолчанию и это корневой логгер, к которому все другие логгеры привязаны.

Поэтому, если хочешь абсолютно независимые логгеры, то дай им обоим названия:

```
logger = register_logger(path, "server", "server", 1)
logger_web = register_logger(path, "web", "web", 1)
```

**UPD:**

Если это решение не подходит, то можно использовать фильтр для хэндлера.

Для этого нужно будет сначала удалить все хэндлеры по умолчанию от root логгера. Затем добавить свой хэндлер, в котором есть фильтр.

А фильтре мы будем принимать только логи, которые пришли от root логгера, а все остальные будут игнорироваться.

```
class OnlyRootFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.name == "root"

logger = logging.getLogger()

for handler in logger.handlers:
    logger.removeHandler(handler)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(OnlyRootFilter())
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Надеюсь идея понятна, это можно внедрить в твою функцию, например с проверкой `if register_name == None:` или подобной.

**UPDUPD** Вот такой простой и короткий вариант:

```py
# Добавим в конце функции register_logger
if register_name is None or register_name == "root":
    handler.addFilter(logging.Filter(name="root"))
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но проблема в том что в одной независимой от общей библиотеки части приложения не очень хочется зависеть от имени. Его же везде потом нужно будет использовать `logging.getLogger("server")`. И мне совсем непонятно, почему `root-logger` вообще что-то к себе привязывает.

Comment: Добавил обновление с использованием фильтра. Это решение точно должно подойти.

Comment: Спасибо. Оказывается `Logger` по умолчанию регистрируется как _"root"_ [github RootLogger](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eda2963378a3c292cf6bb202bb00e94e46ee6d90/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1826). И использовать наследование с переопределением не всегда обязательно. Достаточно явно указать имя в конструкторе фильтра. Это сработало. Добавил в твой ответ короткий рабочий вариант.